# Is it possible to make svn execute a script each time when someone commited something?

Tags: svn

I've install subversion, and want to write my own script to automate the web deployment.

Is it possible to trigger the script when commiting?

It's neither ssh nor apache based, only rely on svnserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, Subversion provides a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) that does exactly this. The Subversion hooks are found in a `hooks` directory in the repository, and the default installation contains template files (`*.tmpl`) that show examples of each type of hook.

Comment: Where to configure that hook/notify svnserve of the hook?

Comment: @user198729: see [Implementing Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) in the Subversion book for detailed information.